# Access to members of a nested class that are public

Tags: c#

I have something like this:

```
public class OuterClass
{
   // other methods and fields... 

    public class InnerClass {
        public int Prop1 {get; set;}
        public int Prop2 {get; set;}
    }
}
```

and then in a `method` I have an object being passed that is of type `OuterClass`.
I thought I can write something like this. But intellisense is not showing it.

```
outerClassobject.InnerClass.Prop1 = 234;
```

Comment: Why would it? For that, you would need a public property/field of type `OuterClass.InnerClass` called `InnerClass`. Your code shows that you declared the class, not that you are using it

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Can you update the class definion the way you say it, so I understand

Comment: `public class OuterClass { public InnerClass Inner { get; set; } // your current stuff... }` (note that the name is `Inner` as it cannot be `InnerClass` as that name is already taken)

Comment: `InnerClass` is not itself a *member* of `OuterClass`, it's just a class with a funky name. If `Prop1` was `static`, you could access it with `OuterClass.InnerClass.Prop1`. As an instance member, you could only access it as a member of some field or property of `OuterClass` that was declared to be of type `InnerClass`.

Comment: Are you by any chance a Java programmer? C# nested classes do not behave like Java inner classes, if that is what is confusing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing classes and objects. You need to access fields or properties of an object:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerClassObject = new OuterClass.InnerClass();
innerClassObject.Prop1 = 234;
```

Or:

```
public class OuterClass
{
   // other methods and fields... 
    public InnerClass InnerClassProp { get; } = new InnerClass();

    public class InnerClass {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    }
}

outerClassobject.InnerClassProp.Prop1 = 234;
```

When you want to access a property of the inner class, you need an instance of it. So in the above example `OuterClass.InnerClass` is instantiated and assigned to `InnerClassProp`.

In your example, the classes are nested. That does not necessarily mean that the instances are nested, too. Conversely, it is also possible that the instances are nested, but the classes are not.

Comment: I would just note that the class does not _have_ to be an inner class in order to be used as a property (will be obvious to most, but perhaps not to the OP).

Comment: oh yeah that's how I wanted to design it to be able to use it this way .. thanks   outerClassobject.InnerClassProp.Prop1 = 234;